# Adding LaunchScreen.storyboard raises unsupported configuration issue

Tags: ios, ios8, storyboard

According to new guidelines, the recommendation is to use a LaunchScreen storyboard instead of the usual images. I've modified an iOS 7 project, converted to iOS 8 and added the storyboard but now I'm getting the warning:

*Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier for runtime access via -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier*

Is there something I'm missing? When you create an iOS 8 project brand new, it uses LaunchScreen.xib instead of LaunchScreen.storyboard, but all the references say to use a storyboard, and don't mention anything about warnings or errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know why they suggest using storyboards as launch screens when XIB files are simpler and generate no errors. Suggest using an XIB.

When you add a file, under iOS | User Interface is Launch Screen. Just copy the elements from your storyboard, paste into the XIB and reset the constraints. Most launch screens are trivial so it shouldn't take long. It helps to make the XIB the same size as the story board.

Comment: But this doesn't seem to work when using a UINavigationBar.
The Bar will be on top of the screen instead ob below the statusbar.